# How to create a "shield" shape using html and CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to create a shape like the one pictured below in just HTML and CSS. I am really not sure how to create the triangular shape at the bottom. The code I currently have is bare minimum because I am really not sure where to start.

```css
    .newBadge {
        flex: inherit;
        height: 130px;
        width: 130px;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, grey, lightgray, lightgray ,grey 1900px);
        /* border-radius: 5px; */
        border: 5%;
        border-color: lightgray;
        border-style: inset;
      }
    
    .background{
    /* height: auto; */
    }
    
    .year{
        flex: auto;
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 20px solid transparent;
        border-right: 20px solid transparent;
        
        border-top: 1px solid #f00;
      
    }
```

```html
<div class="newBadge">

    <div class="background">

    
        <div class="company">
            _______
        </div>

        <div class="title">
            ______
        </div>

        <div class="secondaryTitle">
            ______
        </div>

        <div class="rating">
            *****
        </div>

        <div class="year">
            2021
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

[Shield shaped logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjZUu.png)

Comment: this might help [link](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_polygon.asp)

Comment: Honestly, CSS is not the best solution for this problem. If it's for a test, fair enough, but otherwise you'll always certainly want to consider an image of sorts.

Comment: clip-path can help https://jsfiddle.net/z0w6erm2/ (mask too)

Comment: Yeah, it is actually for real world problem. So when the shape is done, it is going to have multiple instances and but have different words where I have colored out. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo-element along with borders:

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #D5D3D4;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 17%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 50px #D2D0D1;
  border-left: solid 150px transparent;
  border-right: solid 150px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

> ideally I would like it to be about 20% thinner

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: #D5D3D4;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 21%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 50px #D2D0D1;
  border-left: solid 120px transparent;
  border-right: solid 120px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome, but ideally I would like it to be about 20% thinner. I tried editing it myself to achieve that, but had no luck.

Comment: @christianlance I've updated my answer to make it 20% thinner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HTML + CSS required to make a shield:

```css
#parent {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
 
#shield {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 0 0 70% 70%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#shield:before, #shield:after {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50%;
    content:"";
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 53%;
    background: green;
    border-radius: 70% 70% 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-61.5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-61.5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-61.5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-61.5deg);
    transform: rotate(-61.5deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
#shield:after {
    background-color: green;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(61.5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(61.5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(61.5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(61.5deg);
    transform: rotate(61.5deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin :100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="shield">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: This is really nice; however, I would need the bottom to be more triangular with no rounded edges

Answer (score 0):

Use a canvas and mark the points.

```
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="500"></canvas> 

  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        // Stroke color
        context.strokeStyle = "#000";
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(50,100);
        context.lineTo(250,100);
        context.lineTo(250,300);
        // Your design
        context.stroke();
        // Fill with a color
        context.fillStyle = "#824EA8";
        context.fill();
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

In `context.moveTo(50,100);` **50** indicates **x** value from the left side of the canvas and **100** indicates **y** value from the top side of the canvas. Same order for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
<svg width="2000" height="2000">
  <polygon points="50 50, 200 50, 200 200, 125 250, 50 200" style="fill: silver; stroke:black;" />
  
</svg>
```

You can make it with svg, just mark the points, and style it like You want.

Comment: right, my only issue is I still need the words in the spots I had marked out and I;m not sure if you can do that with SVG?

Comment: you can make a div on it, with position:absolute, then  z-index:+1;  and then write on it

Comment: How would you write on it? Just adding a p tag makes the word appear above the shape

Comment: add in css: p {position:absolute; z-index:+1;}  
like this: <p style="position:absolute; z-index:+1;padding-top:80px;padding-left:80px;">Some text</p>

Comment: I added that code and it is still appearing far above the shield,

Comment: <div>
    <p style="position:absolute; z-index:+1;padding-top:80px;padding-left:80px;">Some text</p>
     <svg width="2000" height="2000">
           <polygon points="50 50, 200 50, 200 200, 125 250, 50 200" style="fill: silver; stroke:black;" />
      </svg>
</div>
like this? and still above?

Comment: Ah, that worked much better! Is there a way to do linear gradient background like in the picture?

Comment: sure, you can try this one and play with it:
<div> <p style="position:absolute; z-index:+1;padding-top:80px;padding-left:80px;">Some text</p> <svg width="2000" height="2000"> 
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:silver;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:white;stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
   <polygon points="50 50, 200 50, 200 200, 125 250, 50 200" fill="url(#grad1)" stroke="black"/>
    </svg>
    </div>